# Is it possible to load an obfuscated html in an iframe content?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a doubt. I am having an obfuscated html i want to load that in an iframe component. I want to unobfuscate that before loading it in the iframe component. Is it possible? Is there any javascript tool like that? 
Any ideas?

Added a link.

http://colddata.com/developers/online_tools/obfuscator.shtml#obfuscator_view

Original Code:

obfuscated Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
<!--
var s="=iunm?=cpez?=ejw!dmbtt>#b#?=0ejw?=0cpez?=0iunm?";
m=""; for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) {  if(s.charCodeAt(i) == 28){    m+= '&';} else if (s.charCodeAt(i) == 23) {     m+= '!';} else {    m+=String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i)-1);    }}document.write(m);//-->
</script>
```

So finally i will be having a file like this but when i am about to load in the iframe component i want to see the real code.
The reason why i want use the obfuscated code is because i will be keeping some static html's in an android device and load those html's since i am keeping it in the device i want to obfuscate. Initially i though of encrypting. But this will cause performance impact.

Comment: please elaborate, examples, etc..

Comment: what is the need for unobfuscate  an obfuscated  html ?

Comment: We could use some more information, why is the html obfuscated? How is it obfuscated?

Comment: there are really people out there, that obfuscate html? I MEAN REALLY? with so little effort you can make it readable anyway... or else your website visitor couldnt read it either.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen: Updated. I am creating an phone gap application in android i will be keeping the html in the android device so i want that content to be obfuscated.

Comment: @Najzero: Sorry for not posting the question properly. But i'll be having that html in a local file system and i'll be loading that through an iframe component present at the client side.

Comment: If you simply use a console.log(m) you will be able to see the data that is not obfuscated, you can use this for anything you like. Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/Allan/w9YKH/ I don't get why you want to obfuscate it, it is so easy to make it readable again anyway.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen: Just to have some kind of security boss. Say if i have an encrypted html. I cant decrypt that before loading because it's cpu intensive. So , i was thinking of some alternatives

Comment: @karthick it will do you nothing in terms of security, you need to provide the "key/function" to decrypt it, and people can just use this. If you explain why you need the security and for what data you need it, we might be able to help you.

Comment: @AllanKimmerJensen: I have some static html files in the system which i will load in an iframe component when i request for that html. The files are present in an android device. Since i am keeping the static files in the device i want to protect that somehow from being misused.

Answer (score 2):

To load HTML in an iframe with jQuery:

```
var html = '<div>Your HTML</div>';
$("iframe").contents().find("body").html(html);
```

The iframe's domain and its parent's must match though.

As for the obfuscation thing, don't do that, if you can un-obfuscate it, everybody can as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are obfuscating just for the purpose of preventing people from searching the OS quickly for the content, e.g. to hide solutions in a simple game, this would be acceptable on modern devices:

```
var htmlString = 'this is a test', base64EncodedString = '';

base64EncodedString = window.bToA( htmlString );
```

You then just need to use the following to reverse:

```
htmlString = window.aToB( base64EncodedString );
```

You can then just use Pioul's method for placing it in the iframe.

However as people have stated, obfuscation for other reasons - i.e. proper security protection - is rather pointless, as with a bit of knowledge of your app coders could easily reverse whatever you do *(especially as everything involved in the obfuscation is working client-side)*.